# Como reutilizar um enum em outras telas contendo algumas propriedades diferentes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, enums

Estou trabalhando com um tela "Financeiro" e outra tela "Relatório Financeiro". Para a tela Financeiro, eu criei um enum com as opões "Contas a Pagar e Contas a Receber".

```
public enum  FinanceiroTipo
{
    [Description("CONTAS A PAGAR")]
    ContasPagar = 1,
    [Description("CONTAS A RECEBER")]
    ContasReceber = 2
}
```

Eu gostaria de reaproveitar o enum FinanceiroTipo para a tela Relatório Financeiro (pois não vejo necessidade de se duplicar enumeradores), mas na tela Relatório Financeiro preciso ter um enumerador a mais, sendo 3 enumeradores ao total: "Todos, Contas a pagar e Contas a Receber".

Eu tentei fazer herança, mas no C#, isso não é possível de ser feito com enumeradores.

Alguém teria algumas dicas de boas práticas para resolver o meu problema?
Obrigado!

Comment: Ou são iguais ou não são. DRY não é evitar repetição: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101

Comment: Mas qual o problema em ter o Enum com 3 valores?

Comment: é que na tela de cadastros aopção OUTROS não deve aparecer, pois é específica para relatório.

Comment: `Todos` não são um tipo de operação financeira, logo de forma alguma deve ser incluído no enum `FinanceiroTipo` se você quer usar um enum para popular o filtro na tela de relatório crie um novo `FinanceiroTipoFiltro` com as opções que deseja. Ou por ser apenas um item de exibição, você pode aproveitar `FinanceiroTipo` e adicionar na caixa de seleção o item `Todos` e fazer o tratamento para que quando essa opção for selecionada, simplesmente não fazer o filtro pelo tipo da operação em sua consulta.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Boa sugestão!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma ViewModels e dentro dela você
pode adicionar:

```
public class FinanceiroTipo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool Todos { get; set; }
}
```

no controller

```
private void PreencherCombos()
     {

        ViewBag.FinanceiroTipo = new List<FinanceiroTipo> {
        new FinanceiroTipo {Id = 1, Name="CONTAS A PAGAR",Todos= true },
        new FinanceiroTipo {Id = 2, Name="CONTAS A RECEBER",Todos= true },   
      };

   }
```

na sua View:

```
<div class="col-md-2 mb-20">
   <label asp-for="Ativo" class="control-label"></label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Ativo, ((IEnumerable<StatusViewModel>)ViewBag.FinanceiroTipo).Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
  Text = option.Name,
  Value = option.Id.ToString(),
Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == Model.Ativo)
}), "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control select2" })
<span asp-validation-for="Ativo" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```